# I'm trying to get different values from my While loop I seem to be getting the same value printed 3 times

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, database-backups

I've tried to use a While Loop and I seem to be getting the same value printed 3 times I need to have different values printed.

```sql
DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET @Counter = 1 
WHILE ( @Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempTable_Log))
        --To handle gaps in the looping column value
        BEGIN PRINT @Counter 
        SELECT @LogbackupFile = physical_device_name,  @LogBackupSQL = @LogbackupFile 
      FROM #TempTable_log
      WHERE backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate) 
      AND backup_finish_date > @FullBackupDate 
      AND backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate 
      SET @Counter = @Counter + 1 
      SET @LogBackupSQL = 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK 
      = ''' + @LogbackupFile + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,' 
     PRINT @LogBackupSQL end END
```

Result

```
(3 rows affected)
1
RESTORE LOG ns_lots_of_vlfs_copy FROM  DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.KUSHALRATTU\MSSQL\Backup\ns_lots_of_vlfs_tran_03_10022023.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,
2
RESTORE LOG ns_lots_of_vlfs_copy FROM  DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.KUSHALRATTU\MSSQL\Backup\ns_lots_of_vlfs_tran_03_10022023.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,
3
RESTORE LOG ns_lots_of_vlfs_copy FROM  DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.KUSHALRATTU\MSSQL\Backup\ns_lots_of_vlfs_tran_03_10022023.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,
```

Expected Result

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.KUSHALRATTU\MSSQL\Backup\ns_lots_of_vlfs_tran_03_10022023.trn
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.KUSHALRATTU\MSSQL\Backup\ns_lots_of_vlfs_tran_02_10022023.trn
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.KUSHALRATTU\MSSQL\Backup\ns_lots_of_vlfs_tran_01_10022023.trn
```

Comment: Each loop you're just setting an arbitrary value to your variable `@LogbackupFile`. This is because you aren't changing the `WHERE` and the data in your table `#TempTable_log` doesn't change. If you do the *same* thing 3 times, then you would *expect* the same thing to occur, and that's exactly what is happening here.

Comment: Why are you using a loop here at all? Why not just `SELECT` the data you need in a single statement, with 1 row per `RESTORE` statement?

Comment: The idea is if there are more than one transaction log it would get the Restore Statements for however many logs there are in the sys table. If I add Counter = Counter +1 to the Where clause it just adds the count value i.e 1,2,3.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the reason for the behaviour is because each iteration of your loop you are doing the *same* thing. In your SQL you are assigning an arbitrary value to you variable `@LogbackupFile` and as this value is from a temporary table it has a high likelihood that that arbitrary value will be the same value *every* time.

Effectively you are doing something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Temp (I int)

INSERT INTO #Temp (I)
VALUES(1),(3),(2); --Intentionally in an "odd" order
GO

DECLARE @C int = 1;
DECLARE @I int;

WHILE @C <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp) BEGIN
    --Assign an arbitrary value to @i
    SELECT @I = I
    FROM #Temp;

   PRINT @I;
   SET @C = @C + 1;
END;
GO

DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

This, very likely, returns the value `2` 3 times.

In truth, I'm not sure why you want to `PRINT` these values. Why not just `SELECT` the dataset you need? This will return multiple rows with a separate `RESTORE LOG` on each line:

```sql
SELECT 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + physical_device_name + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,'
FROM #TempTable_log
WHERE backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate) 
  AND backup_finish_date > @FullBackupDate 
  AND backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate
ORDER BY backup_finish_date;
```

If you *must* `PRINT` it, you could use string aggregation, *assuming* that the total value will be less than 8,000 bytes:

```
DECLARE @Restore nvarchar(4000),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @Restore = STRING_AGG('RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + physical_device_name + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,',@CRLF) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY backup_finish_date)
FROM #TempTable_log
WHERE backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate) 
  AND backup_finish_date > @FullBackupDate 
  AND backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate;

PRINT @Restore;
```

If you *must* use a `WHILE` lop (which I suggest against), you need to ensure that you assign a different value each iteration. As I can't see your data, and thus don't know what it in the table, one method would be to `DELETE` the "first" row each iteration, so that you get a different row each time. This *assumes* that `backup_finish_date` and `physical_device_name` are npth **unique** values.

```sql
DECLARE @Counter int;
SET @Counter = 1;
WHILE (@Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM #TempTable_Log))

BEGIN
    PRINT @Counter;

    SELECT TOP (1)
           @LogbackupFile = physical_device_name,
           @LogBackupSQL = @LogbackupFile
    FROM #TempTable_log
    WHERE backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate)
      AND backup_finish_date > @FullBackupDate
      AND backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate
    ORDER BY backup_finish_date;

    SET @Counter = @Counter; --I assume this should start at 1, not 2?
    SET @LogBackupSQL = 'RESTORE LOG ' + @DatabaseNameCopy + ' FROM  DISK  = ''' + @LogbackupFile + ''' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5,';
    PRINT @LogBackupSQL;

    DELETE FROM #TempTable_log
    WHERE physical_device_name = @LogbackupFile;
END;
```